# Reusable enum types in json schema

Tags: java, json, schema

I'm trying to define reusable enum types with json schema (input for phoenixnap/springmvc-raml-plugin).

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema",
  "definitions": {
    "MyEnum": {
      "type": "object",
      "javaType": "foo.bar.MyEnum",
        "properties": {
          "Value": { "enum": [ "OPT_1", "OPT_2" ] }
        },
      "required": ["Value"]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to define the schema without the "Value" property and use the enum values directly?

Answer (score 1):

schema definition with top level enum

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema",
  "definitions": {
  "MyEnum": {
    "type": "object",
    "javaType": "foo.bar.MyEnum",
    "enum": [ "OPT_1", "OPT_2" ]
    }
  }
}
```